# ExpressionEngine: File Manager

Tags: codeigniter-2, expressionengine

I’m new to EE and trying to learn the basics. Some questions about the File Manager:

1. I upload a photo and put “cat, kitten” in the description. When I do a search for “kitten”, it finds the photo. But when I do a search for “cat”, I get nothing. Any ideas what’s going on?
2. The file metadata are: file title, file name, description, credit, and location. What if I wanted to add custom fields? How do I do that?
3. In the template files, how do I access a particular manipulation (I call this “rendition”) of an image? Say I define a rendition “thumbnail” to be 100x100. How do I access that particular rendition in a template?
4. Is there a way to randomize the file names of the files being uploaded?
5. After uploading an image and testing it against PageSpeed, it turns out that the image can still be optimized via losslessly compressing it. How can this problem be addressed?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the file manager. Not EE's brightest spot.

1. It would not surprise me if the search in the File Manager was not
   very robust. I'd try more variations to narrow it down (what kind of
   characters affect the results - commas, dashes, spaces, etc ... do
   partial terms match?)
2. You cannot currently add custom metadata to files in the file manager.
3. Use this syntax: `{field_name:rendition}`, e.g.,
   `{my_image:thumbnail}` ([docs](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/custom_fields.html#id11)).
4. Nope.
5. EE just uses the GD library available in your PHP install to resize
   images. If you want the highest possible optimization, you'll have
   to do your image manipulations yourself.

Given your queries, I would suggest you have a look at [Assets](http://pixelandtonic.com/assets) by Pixel and Tonic. It offers a far superior file management experience on most of these fronts.

Comment: Just to add to this, as far as I'm aware file searches only take into account file names and titles (which are almost always the same thing). Re points 3 - 5, due to EE's weaknesses here it's usually best to use a plugin to generate image manipulations. [CE Image](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image) is a must-have for all of my EE projects these days.

Comment: For sure another vote here for CE Image. It also has an extension add-on called [CE Lossless](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-lossless) which provides the more advanced levels of compression you might be looking for.

Comment: As said above I've found a combination of Pixel and tonic's Assets with CE Image to be a winner. Add CE Lossless if you need further file size reductions to the images CE Image already produces.